# How render React on server to callback function?

Tags: reactjs, render

I want render react-app on server with full lifecycle and updates supports.

Like https://github.com/Yomguithereal/react-blessed, but not to terminal, to callback-function.

Example, pseudo-code:

```
render(<MyComponent />, (tree)=>{
    console.log(tree); // new react component-tree
})
```

Another example, https://github.com/iamdustan/react-hardware

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/077d660a2727e3d3d6629d3a62693f8509100139/src/renderers/testing/ReactTestRenderer.js#L138

Comment: Most react component are themselves functions, so I'm not sure what you are wishing to achieve. 
How would your "new react component-tree" be different from just a "unrendered" react component? 
What format would you expect the `tree` to have? It would help if you could elaborate and describe your use case in more details (you can edit your original question).

Comment: @MichałCzapliński, tree can be, example, DOM or jsonable-DOM, it is not important, need update-callback calling.

Comment: Again, it is not clear what you are asking for... Please take some time to phrase your question more clearly and elaborate on your use-case. There is a number of popular server-side rendering frameworks, take a look at those:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js
https://github.com/redfin/react-server

However, if I understand you correctly, you would need to emulate the DOM with sth like JSDOM (https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and then render the whole component with sth like `mount()` in enzyme (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme)

Comment: Look my example (react-blessed), yes, i no need just server-rendering, but no, i no need just a working with dom (like, jsdom). I need to work react with other environment (like, react-native) and other components, than DOM-elements. Another example, https://github.com/iamdustan/react-hardware

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to implement a "custom renderer" for react. Here's an article that I found that could be helpful: 
http://goshakkk.name/react-custom-renderers/

Comment: Thanks! It can help me little bit.